# Estilo redondeado table html

Tags: html, css, xhtml2pdf

Saludos deseo obtener un formato como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualizacion**
el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo:

```html
<style>
    .clase_table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 10;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>
                <table class="clase_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>R.U.C.:</b> {{ ruc_empresa }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td><b>FACTURA:</b>{{ numero_factura }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>NÚMERO DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b><br>{{ clave_acceso }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>FECHA Y HORA DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><b>AMBIENTE:</b> PRUEBAS</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>EMISIÓN:</b> NORMAL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><b>CLAVE DE ACCESO:</b><br>{{ clave_acceso }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="static/images/barcode_example.png" width="300" height="50" alt=""></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**Actualizacion 26-12-2018**

Este codigo genera en efecto los bordes deseados, pero debido a que uso una libreria **Xhtml2PDF** no aplica ciertos estilos como:

```
background-color
border-bottom-color, border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width
border-left-color, border-left-style, border-left-width
border-right-color, border-right-style, border-right-width
border-top-color, border-top-style, border-top-width
colordisplay
font-family, font-size, font-style, font-weight
height
line-height, list-style-type
margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top
padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
page-break-after, page-break-before
size
text-align, text-decoration, text-indent
vertical-align
white-space
width
zoom
```

Quiza alguien me podria guiar o indicar en que estoy fallando. gracias..!!

Comment: No comprendo bien cual es el problema que te genera, el codigo que tenes redondea bien los bordes de la tabla lo acabo de verificar, ahora si tenes 4 tablas y solo queres que salga en 1 crea una clase css y llamala solo de la tabla que necesites. es eso? https://jsfiddle.net/wvLatrhq/

Comment: Tendrias que pones mas codigo, parte de la tabla o del css, tal vez tenes un estilo anterior que esta poniendo bordes a toda la tabla, y ahora queres poner el nuevo pero te sigue tomando el anterior, porque como te mostre en el ejeplo de arriba ese css q pones hace lo q necesitas. Dale click derecho a la tabla / inspeccionar y mira los estilos que tiene, si tiene otros es porque hay un estilo antes del que vos queres poner https://i.imgur.com/nqehRfG.png

Comment: ¿Deseas que se aplique el borde o que no se aplique?@Tegito123

Comment: deseo que se aplique solo los bordes externos y redondeados como la imagen de arriba...

Comment: @Tegito123 pensaría que te faltaba agregar :      border:solid black 1px;          border-radius:10px; pero ahora veo tu actualización, es un poco extraño, ¿Que navegador usas?

Comment: Uso sistema operativo CentOS Mozilla 60.02

Comment: @Tegito123 agrega: -webkit-border-radius: 10px;!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crea la clase que utilizaría tu tabla y definela solo a las tablas que desees con borde redondeado:

```
  .round_table {
                    border-collapse:separate;
                    border-spacing: 10;
                    border:solid black 1px;
                    border-radius:10px;
                    -moz-border-radius:10px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
                }
```

...
...

```
  <table class=round_table >
```

Si deseas que funcione para todos los browsers es importante definir:

```
 border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

Ejemplo:

```css
 
    
       .round_table {                   
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 10;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            padding: 2px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        }
      
      table {                   
         border-collapse: separate;
         border-spacing: 10;
         border: 1px solid black;        
         padding: 2px;
        }
            
            th {
                border-left:solid black 1px;
                border-top:solid black 1px;
            }    
            th {
                background-color: orange;
                border-top: none;
            }
```

```html
         <table>        
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Elena</td>
                    <td>Cute</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Tegito123</td>
                    <td>Quiet</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Jorge</td>
                    <td>Crazy</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    
   
    
            <table class=round_table >        
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Elena</td>
                    <td>Cute</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Tegito123</td>
                    <td>Quiet</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Jorge</td>
                    <td>Crazy</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Como lo tienes se le aplica el estilo a todos las etiquetas `<table>`
Define una clase y aplicarle solo a las tablas que quieras modificar.

Ejemplo:

```css
.clase_table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 10;
    }
    .clase_table{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <table class="clase_table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respetando Tu Código Puedes Hacer Esto Para Que Todas Las Columnas ( Elementos  ) de la Tabla Cojan el Formato del CSS, si pones mas Columnas en Filas ( Elementos  ) puedes cambiar el class="clase_table" y poner-lo en vez de en la columna en la fila...

```html
<style>
.clase_table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
<table class="clase_table">
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>R.U.C.:</b> {{ ruc_empresa }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>FACTURA:</b>{{ numero_factura }} </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>NÚMERO DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b><br>{{ clave_acceso }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>FECHA Y HORA DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>AMBIENTE:</b> PRUEBAS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>EMISIÓN:</b> NORMAL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clase_table" ><b>CLAVE DE ACCESO:</b><br>{{ clave_acceso }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="clase_table" ><img src="static/images/barcode_example.png" width="300" height="50" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la propiedad

```css
border-collapse: collapse
```

No permite que se establezcan los bordes redondeados, igual como no estás utilizando los bordes definidos en las etiquetas `<td>` y `<th>`, puedes eliminar `border-collapse` y debería bastar para que `border-radius` entre en efecto.